# Keras Callbacks: Learnig Rate Schedular and Reduce Learning rate on plateau

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use both the **LearningRateScheduler** and **ReduceLROnPlateau** callbacks together in Keras, will it make a problem for the learning rate. If so which learning rate will the model use ?

I have faced this problem when trying it which affected my model accuracy.
Like in this
[image]

In the case where my acc: 0.8778 -> 0.8188.

Which do you think was the learning rate at that point.

Comment: This is confusing. I am not sure what you are trying to do. If you want to achieve a functionality which is a combination of `LearningRateScheduler` and `ReduceLROnPlateau`, why don't you implement one yourself? Also, you could print out the learning rate of the model to know what was the LR at a specific epoch. It is difficult to say for us only based on this print log.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar
Can i acheive a combination by using both callbacks or do i have to implement one ? Also can you give me an idea on how to implement this combination or point me to any source that does, cause i can't seem to find any.

Comment: I am not sure what you are exactly trying to do, so it is difficult for me to answer the first part of your question (you simply mention that you want to use both callbacks which is not giving much information on how you want your LR schedule to look like). Regarding the second question, you can see [this](https://www.kaggle.com/fergusoci/keras-loss-based-learning-rate-scheduler), [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/using-learning-rate-schedules-deep-learning-models-python-keras/) and [this](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/nn-learning-rate/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ReduceLROnPlateau, lr changes at the end of previous epoch,
In LearningRateScheduler lr changes at the beginning of current epoch.

therefore, LearningRateScheduler always wins.

Answer (score 1):

The model will make use of both 'ReduceLROnPlateau' and 'LearningRateScheduler' provided they are being used in your model.

1. 'ReduceLROnPlateau' adjusts after the end of the epoch(epoch #
   depends upon the "patience" arguments passed to the
   'ReduceLROnPlateau' class object.
2. 'LearningRateScheduler' adjusts before each epoch(epoch # depends
   upon the definition of a custom scheduler passed to
   'LearningRateScheduler')

In your case learning rate was reduced more which potentially lowered your accuracy.
Better to use EarlyStopping so that the model accuracy doesn't get impacted because of changes in learning rate.